# is it possible to round the last 3 digits of a number in c?

Tags: c, math, numbers, rounding, ceil

i would like to round the last 3 digits of the float number `169786.122` and leaving only 3 digits

is it possible to do it with the math.h library and the ceil function?

in case of `169786.122` == `170`

in case of `169121.122` == `169`

in case of `171126.122` == `171`

in case of `179911.122` == `180`

.. and so on

```c
float aNum = 169726.122;

int main() {

    printf("%.0f\n",aNum); // result 169726
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Divide by 1000, call `ceil`.  (That discards 3 digits, although it's obviously not guaranteed to leave you with 3 digits.)

Comment: Why should the second one be `169` instead of `170`? `ceil` always rounds up. It looks like you actually mean `round`.

Comment: @SteveSummit great will try it now

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right

Comment: @SteveSummit  your comment was the solution to this question 

Comment: Please create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If:

- breaking ties by choosing the even multiple of 1000 is satisfactory,
- the desired multiple of 1000 is representable in the `float` format, and
- the `float` format uses base two or ten,

then `(x - remainderf(x, 1000)) / 1000` calculates the desired result.

This works because the `remainderf` function always produces an exact result (has no rounding error) and, if the desired multiple of 1000 is representable, then the subtraction produces that multiple with no rounding error. If the floating-point format uses base ten, the division just changes the exponent and has no rounding error. If the format uses base two, the division of a multiple of 125 by 125 times a power of two cannot increase the number of significant bits, so the result must fit in the significand, so there is no rounding error.

These caveats are not strict; I expect various improvements are available. In particular, if `nearbyint((x - remainderf(x, 1000)) / 1000)` is used, with the IEEE-754 “single precision” format (binary32), it gets correct results for all cases in which the desired result is representable.